# Kohana validation - why my custom rule always return true?

Tags: php, kohana

Why my custom rule always return true?
My Controller:

```
class Controller_Users extends Controller {
    public function action_func() {
        if ($_POST) {
            $validation = Validation::factory($_POST);
            $validation->rule('field', 'Test::func', array(':value'));
            $check = $validation->check(); // always true
        }
    }
}
```

And class Test:

```
class Test {
    static public function func($value) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Clearly indicated - false. But `->check()` returns true. Why? And how to fix it?

Comment: You may need `class Test extends ORM` instead?

Comment: no, this is not a model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you need use `$validation->error()`

```
class Controller_Users extends Controller {
    public function action_func() {
        if ($_POST) {
            $validation = Validation::factory($_POST);
            $validation->label('field','Some label')
            $validation->rule('field', 'Test::func', array(':value',':validation'));
            $check = $validation->check(); // always true
        }
    }
}
```

And class Test:

```
class Test {
    static public function func($value, $validation) {
        $validation->error('field','Some error desc');
        return false;
    }
}
```